# Selenium interpret javascript on mac?

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, mechanize

I'm trying to make a web crawler that click on ads (yes, i know), it's very sophisticated, but, I realise that Google Ads aren't showed when javascript is disabled. Today, i use Mechanize, and it doesn't "accept" javasript.
I heard selenium use another system to crawl the net.
The only thing I want to do is access my page, and click on the ad (generated by javascript).
Can Selenium do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) is a *browser automation tool*. You can basically automate everything you can do in your browser. Start with going through the [Getting Started](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html) section of the documentation.

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

print driver.title

driver.close()
```

Besides automating common browsers, like Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Internet Explorer, you can also use [`PhantomJS` headless browser](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: So ... can i do what I want ? or is it just a bot like "go there, go there, go there" ?

Comment: @martinsurleweb from what you've described - it is definitely doable. If you have difficulties implementing it, you can provide a link to the website and point to the ad you want to click and I'll try to help.